# O Gunicorn não está funcionando, pois está dando o seguinte erro gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'. error

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, nginx

Boa noite,

Fiz uma tentativa de deploy do meu site em linguagem Django, mas sem sucesso. Os erros que me surgiram depois estão apresentados abaixo.

Agradeço toda a ajuda, pois já fiz muita pesquisa e várias correções, mas sem resultados positivos.

Após fazer a seguinte checagem:

**sudo systemctl status gunicorn.socket**

Surge-me o erro abaixo:

```
Failed to dump process list, ignoring: No such file or directory
● gunicorn.socket - gunicorn socket
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.socket; enabled; vendor preset:
enabled)
   Active: active (listening) since Thu 2020-03-12 19:56:45 WET; 1min
 24s ago
   Listen: /run/gunicorn.sock (Stream)
   CGroup: /system.slice/gunicorn.socket

Mar 12 19:56:45 cursopython systemd[1]: Listening on gunicorn socket.
```

Após fazer a seguinte checagem

**sudo systemctl status gunicorn**

Surge o erro abaixo:

```
● gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; disabled; vendor preset
: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2020-03-12 19:54:59 W
ET; 5min ago
 Main PID: 19701 (code=exited, status=3)

Mar 12 19:54:59 cursopython gunicorn[19701]: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyCo
nfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.
Mar 12 19:54:59 cursopython gunicorn[19701]: Did you install mysqlclient?
Mar 12 19:54:59 cursopython gunicorn[19701]: [2020-03-12 19:54:59 +0000] [19727]
 [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 19727)
Mar 12 19:54:59 cursopython gunicorn[19701]: [2020-03-12 19:54:59 +0000] [19701]
 [INFO] Shutting down: Master
Mar 12 19:54:59 cursopython gunicorn[19701]: [2020-03-12 19:54:59 +0000] [19701]
 [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
Mar 12 19:54:59 cursopython systemd[1]: gunicorn.service
: Main process exited, code=exited, status=3/NOTIMPLEMENTED
Mar 12 19:54:59 cursopython systemd[1]: gunicorn.service
: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 12 19:54:59 cursopython systemd[1]: gunicorn.service
: Start request repeated too quickly.
Mar 12 19:54:59 cursopython systemd[1]: gunicorn.service
```

Toda a ajuda é bem vinda.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo erro que está aparecendo, o sistema está tendo problemas para carregar a biblioteca de conexão com o MySQL. Verifique se você não esqueceu de instalar e se ela está funcionando direitinho.